# Can't retrieve the value of spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am implementing one custom spinner for my app where I am using hidden field values. It's working but when I update again the item which is saved at first time is not showing on spinner I need it will show on spinner. thank you below is my code.

```
    final MyData items[] = new MyData[25];
    items[14] = new MyData("5ft 1in","154");
    items[15] = new MyData("5ft 2in","157");
    items[16] = new MyData("5ft 3in","160");
    items[17] = new MyData("5ft 4in","162");
    items[18] = new MyData("5ft 5in","165");
    items[19] = new MyData("5ft 6in","167");
    items[20] = new MyData("5ft 7in","170");
    items[21] = new MyData("5ft 8in","172");
    items[22] = new MyData("5ft 9in","175" );
    items[23] = new MyData("5ft 10in","177");
    items[24] = new MyData("5ft 11in","180");
    items[25] = new MyData("5ft 12in","182");
    items[26] = new MyData("6ft 1in","185");
    items[27] = new MyData("6ft 2in","187");
    items[28] = new MyData("6ft 3in","190");
    items[29] = new MyData("6ft 4in","193");
    items[30] = new MyData("6ft 5in","195");
    items[31] = new MyData("6ft 6in","198");
    items[32] = new MyData("6ft 7in","201");
    items[33] = new MyData("6ft 8in","203");
    items[34] = new MyData("6ft 9in","206");
    items[35] = new MyData("6ft 10in","208");
    items[36] = new MyData("6ft 11in","211");
    items[37] = new MyData("6ft 12in","213");
    items[38] = new MyData("Above 7ft","217");
    ArrayAdapter<MyData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyData>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinHeight1.setAdapter(adapter);
    for(int i=0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        if (partnerHeight1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(adapter.getItem(i).toString())) {
            spinHeight1.setSelection(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    spinHeight1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            MyData d = items[i];
            heightFrom=d.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you debug your code ? Is your for loop is executing or not? Because you are checking instantly after setting adaptor

Comment: do you want selected value ?

Comment: Yep I want selected value.

Comment: for loop is executing @JRamesh

Comment: @VikasGodiyal Is partnerHeight1 is instance of MyData ?

Comment: Sorry for loop is not working

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
 spinHeight1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

heightFrom=spinHeight1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: have you debug ? your cursor is going inside or not at heightfrom=

Comment: I used Log.e("heightfrom",heightfrom); which is not print on log

Comment: But other item is coming

Comment: what is other item?

Comment: other spinners item like country name and education details

Comment: ok your this line is working fine ` spinHeight1.setSelection(i);`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156425/discussion-between-vikas-godiyal-and-hasmukh-kachhatiya).

Answer (score 1):

if partnerHeight1 is string then

```
for(int i=0; i < items.length; i++) {

        if (partnerHeight1.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(items[i].getValue())) {
            spinHeight1.setSelection(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

if partnerHeight1 is MyData then

```
for(int i=0; i < items.length; i++) {

        if (partnerHeight1.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(items[i].getValue())) {
            spinHeight1.setSelection(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is message function

Comment: MyData member  accessing method I am considering two members id and message

Comment: this method is not resolving

Comment: @VikasGodiyal Is your adapter.getItem(i) returns MyData ?

Comment: When I am selecting the item then the hidden value is stored successfully on server. It means its working proprly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156419/discussion-between-j-ramesh-and-vikas-godiyal).

Comment: @VikasGodiyal 
I know that but I want to know you are save object of MyData or only value(value/id)

Comment: value id @JRamesh

Comment: @VikasGodiyal check first option in my answer it will work only update checking method getValue()/getID()

Comment: @VikasGodiyal Is your for loop is executing or not? make sure that your code is after 1 second or onResume() not after setAdapter() because it takes time for view intialization

Comment: For loop is not executing because when I used log after setAdapter it shows   data as 4ft3in but when I add log after spinHeight1.setSelection(i); it is not printing

Comment: I am not using onResume method

Comment: "4ft3in" is correct value? or this is 0th position of array?

Comment: Please check full code which I sent on discussion page

Answer (score 0):

If data of an adapter is changed for that data to be reflected to view `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

void notifyDataSetChanged ()

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.